# Compiler won't let me instantiate struct

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

Usually this error shows up when declaring functions and goes away by adding "memory" next to the argument, but this time I can't get it to resolve. I'm trying to instantiate a struct that takes in two parameters:

```
struct Obj {
    string where;
    uint what;
    }


function do() public {
    Obj obj=Obj("here",1);
    }
```

the line with the new Obj triggers:

> TypeError: Data location must be "storage", "memory" or "calldata" for variable, but none was given.

I tried putting "memory" all over the place, after the first argument, after the second, after both, after the function, etc. Nothing seems to appease the compiler.

I'm using pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

Comment: where is `obj` (the variable) defined?

Comment: also you may get better answers [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @CherryDT the function do() creates the variable of the type that is defined literally 4 lines above

Comment: I only see the definition of the struct and the assignment of the variable, not the definition of the variable. The reason I ask is because the data location (storage/memory) would need to be set _there_.

Comment: I updated the code to contain the declaration in front of the variable.

Comment: I did Obj memory obj = Obj("hopa",1) and it works!!! Thanks for the nudge @CherryDT. If you want, copy/paste the comment as an answer and I'll validate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to define the datatype (`Obj`), then the location (`memory` or `storage`), and the variable name (`obj`) is after that.

```
function foo() public {
    Obj memory obj = Obj("here", 1);
}
```